# Make a currency value in gridview negative if positive and vice versa

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Hi I have a gridview that displays currency in the final column. This is a calculated value from a datatable pre databind.

[image: Grid view]

The asp.net used to create this is as follows.

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PONC" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
        <Itemtemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPONC" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PONC", "{0:c}") %>'></asp:Label>
        </Itemtemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I would like to reverse the sign of the value if possible so if its negative display positive and vice versa.  How do I go about this?  Is there anything I can add in the `Eval` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:-

```
Text='<%# String.Format("{0:c}",Convert.ToDouble(Eval("PONC")) * -1) %>'
```

Convert the object to double or in whatever datatype it is (decimal\int) then multiply it with `-1`. Finally format it to display as currency.

But, IMHO you should do it at either DB side or in server code as conversions may result in exceptions if data is not proper.